# P5.js, Node & The Twitter API

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, twitter, p5.js

I've hit a roadblock with a project I've been working on and I'm wondering if somebody could help me out with this.

So, I'm trying to develop a node.js application that queries the Twitter API using a HTML form - that then uses the data retrieved (in JSON form) to visualise the tweets in a P5.js sketch.

Thus far I've been able to use a form that queries the API and writes the pulled tweets to a JSON file. **Separately**, I've also been able to pull in a JSON file to P5 and manipulate the data as I see fit.

The problem is - my end game is that I want it to all be a seamless process, I need the sketch to be served to the user initially, loading in a default data set. However, I need the form to update the sketch on the fly (using AJAX I'd imagine?)

My question is: Is there a less convoluted way of achieving that ^? I'm guessing using a combination of JQuery & Ajax, but I'm frazzled with trying to discern what would run client side and what would run server side.

**TL;DR - I want to pass user inputted data as arguments to query the Twitter API and asynchronously update a p5.js sketch.**

I've attached the code I'm working with so far, I would be massively grateful if somebody could help me with this so I don't have to pull out any more hair! Even pointing me in the right direction would be a huge help.

Thanks in advance :)

Server.js

```
var http = require('http'),
    util = require('util'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    url = require('url'),
    qs = require('querystring');

//Imports the Twit package
var Twit = require('twit');
var totalTweets = [];
var query;
var tweetcount;


//Imports the JSONFILE package
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile')
jsonfile.spaces = 3


//Creates new Twit object
var T = new Twit({
      consumer_key:         'x'
    , consumer_secret:      'x'
    , access_token:         'x'
    , access_token_secret:  'x'     
})    


    //Parameters for the search
    var params = {
        q: "Hello",
        lang:" ",
        count: 70
    }


var server = http.createServer(function (req,res){

    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url,true);
    //console.log(url_parts);

    var body = '';
    if(req.method === 'POST'){
       // res.end('post');
       console.log('Request found with POST method');     
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
            console.log('got data:'+data);
        });
        req.on('end', function () {

            var POST = qs.parse(body);
            // use POST
            res.end("Sent data are name:"+POST.name+" age:"+POST.age);

        });


    } else {
    console.log('Request found with GET method');     
    req.on('data',function(data){ res.end(' data event: '+data);});
    if(url_parts.pathname == '/')

    fs.readFile('./form.html',function(error,data){ 
    console.log('Serving the page form.html');
    res.end(data);    
    });

    else if(url_parts.pathname == '/getData'){
         console.log('Serving the Got Data.');
        getData(res,url_parts);
    }
        }

});
server.listen(8080);
console.log('Server listenning at localhost:8080');



function  getData(res,url_parts){
 console.log("Data submitted by the user name: "+url_parts.query.name+" and age:"+url_parts.query.age);
        res.end("Data submitted by the user name: "+url_parts.query.name+" and age: "+url_parts.query.age);

tweetcount = url_parts.query.age;
query = url_parts.query.name;

console.log(tweetcount + query);


    //Parameters for the search
    var params = {
        q: query,
        lang:" ",
        count: tweetcount
    }


//Searches Twitter Based on arguments
T.get('search/tweets', params, gotData)
function gotData(err, data, response){
var tweets = data.statuses;


//Creates a loop that stores tweets in an array
for (var i=0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
    totalTweets[i] = {
        Username: "@" + tweets[i].user.name,
        Tweet: tweets[i].text,
        Time: tweets[i].created_at
    };
}



var file = 'tweets.json'
//var obj = JSON.stringify(pulledtweets);
//Writes contents of array to JSON file
jsonfile.writeFileSync(file, totalTweets);
//jsonfile.writeFileSync(file, JSON.stringify(obj)) 
console.log("File written successfully");
console.log("Total number of tweets : " + tweets.length);
}
}
```

Sketch.js

```
var myTweets;
var x;
var brokenTweet;
var totalWords = [];
var currentTweet;
var obj = { };



console.log(obj);

function preload() {
  var tweetsFile = "tweets.JSON"
  myTweets = loadJSON(tweetsFile);
}


console.log(totalTweets);

function setup(){
createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight);
background(255);

fill(125);
ellipse(100,100,50,50);

x = 1;
  // create canvas
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  input = createInput();
  input.position(width/2 - input.width/2, 100);

  button = createButton('submit');
  button.position(input.x + input.width, 100);

  textAlign(CENTER);
  textSize(50);
  console.log(myTweets[x].Tweet);
}


function draw(){
background(255);
textSize(18);
fill(0);
text(myTweets[x].Tweet,input.x-25,input.y+50, 300,300);
}

function greet(){
}

function keyPressed(){
if(keyCode == UP_ARROW){
  x++;


console.log(Object.keys(myTweets).length);


//Object.keys counts the amount of object in JSON file
for(var i = 0; i < (Object.keys(myTweets).length) ; i++){
currentTweet = JSON.stringify(myTweets[i].Tweet);
brokenTweet = currentTweet.split(" ");
//console.log(brokenTweet);
  for(var a = 0; a < brokenTweet.length; a++){
    var currentWord = brokenTweet[a];
   // console.log(currentWord);
    totalWords.push(currentWord.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, ''));
  }
//console.log(totalWords);
}





//Loops through array and 
for (var i = 0, j = totalWords.length; i < j; i++) {
   if (obj[totalWords[i]]) {
      obj[totalWords[i]]++;
   }
   else {
      obj[totalWords[i]] = 1;
   } 
}




console.log(obj);

}

if(keyCode == DOWN_ARROW){
  x--;
  if(x < 0){
    x = 0;
  }
}


}
```

form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="getData">
  <p>
  <label><label>Please Fill up the form and submit.<br />
  </label>Name
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Please Input Name" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Age
        <input type="number" name="age" value="25" id="age" placeholder="Please Input Age" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </label>
  </p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now this question is pretty hard to answer. Stack Overflow isn't designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions.

You'll also have better luck if you try to isolate the problem. You could create an example application that has a form that submits to a server, a server that simply saves the form contents to a file, and a P5.js sketch that loads the contents of the file to display a string on screen. That would contain all of the "moving pieces" you need, without any of the extra stuff that's not directly related to your question.

I strongly recommend you try putting together a smaller example app like that first. It's good that you've broken your problem down into two pieces (submitting the form and fetching the json), but now you need to break it down in another way: start with a basic app, and then add the actual logic after you have the connections working.

I will say that your general approach should work. You'd do something like this:

- Create an HTML file that contains a form as well as a P5.js sketch. You can load a default data set if you want.
- When the user clicks a button in the form, use AJAX to send a request to the server containing the form data.
- Have the server do whatever processing and then respond to the request with the JSON content. Again, start with a very simple example before trying to get real results.
- Then on the client side, use the JSON response to modify your P5.js sketch however you want.

Start with a basic example, and if you get stuck on a specific question then please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question, and we'll go from there. Good luck.